# nodejs function returning undefined mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a function that checks if a user is admin or not. If it finds the user id in the database table, it needs to return `true`, otherwise it needs to return `false`, but I'm getting `undefined`. Can you help me?

```
function isAdmin(useruid) {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM admins", function(err,rows,field) {
    if(!err) {
  
      rows.forEach(function(element) {
        if (useruid === element.uid) {
          console.log("[is admin] Found admins!")
          return true;

        } else {
          console.log("[is admin] User is not admin!")
          return false;
        }
      });
  
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }
  })
}
```

I added `;` on the missing lines. I'm receiving output of the console.logs, but the function is still returning `undefined` instead of `false` or `true`.

It looks like:

```
function isAdmin(useruid) {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM admins", function(err,rows,field) {

    if(!err) {
      rows.forEach(function(element) {
        if (useruid === element.uid) {
          console.log("[is admin] Found admins!");
          return true;
        } else {
          console.log("[is admin] User is not admin!");
          return false;
        }
      });
  
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: What did you expect would return to variable `rows` if there are no records match your query (not admin)?

Comment: There is matching records, and also if there is no matching records it should return False, but im recieving "undefined" :)

Comment: I see. Please include in your question which line throw the `undefined` error.

Comment: I don't know that. when i run function like: console.log(isAdmin("adminid")); im getting "undefined"

edit: also when i put in in if statement it can't work because output is always undefined

Comment: Don't know if this is related but multiple line is missing `;`. Besides, consider adding more console.log for debugging. Like before `if(!err)`

Comment: I added ; on the missing lines so now it looks like: 

`
function isAdmin(useruid) {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM admins", function(err,rows,field) {


    if(!err) {
      rows.forEach(function(element) {
        if (useruid === element.uid) {
          console.log("[is admin] Found admins!");
          return true;
        } else {
          console.log("[is admin] User is not admin!");
          return false;
        }
      });
  
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }
  })
}
`

Comment: but i don't know why it doesnt return true or false, im recieving output of console.logs but not the return of function (true/false)

Comment: arr... I see it. The return function is a layer below the outer function.

Comment: I edited post, yes i know its layer below the outer function but how can i retrn it? because i need that forEach to check is the user admin or not.

Comment: The solution is much more complex then I anticipated, please see this [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-the-asynchronous-nature-of-nodejs--net-36183) for hints

Answer (score 1):

As noted the solution is more complicated than you might suspect given the asynchronous nature of Node. There are several ways to address the issue your question presents but I'll include just one here that is relatively flexible and lightweight.

The good news is your function `isAdmin` and the query it includes can be made much simpler so you'll pick up some lines of code there.

Since you start with a UID and your goal is only to check that it exists in the table, you can use a targeted query and skip all the result looping. This will save time and resources in Node as well as MySQL.

**Updated Function**
Note this is now an `async` function with a `Promise`. This way we can later call and `await` the results. Also the `db.query` takes an argument for the `?` placeholder. We pass it our `useruid` variable.

```
const isAdmin = async (useruid) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query('SELECT uid FROM admins WHERE uid = ?;', useruid, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) reject(error);

      // when we get our results we can simply check for length
      // if we have length, there was a match
      // if we have no length, there was no match
      resolve(results.length ? true : false)
    });
  });
};
```

**To call the function…**
We must wrap in `async` function if we want to leverage `await`

```
(async function(){
  let is_admin = await isAdmin(YOUR_UID_VALUE);
  console.log('is_admin', is_admin);
})();
```